# Concurrency problem during upsert in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'd like to insert or update a document in MongoDB based on if a document with that id already exists.

**My object**

```
long _Id                 // Generated by myself (requirement)
List<Products> Products
```

**Desired insert behaviour**

Check if a shop object with id X exists. If not? Insert object with given id and a new products list.

**Desired update behaviour**

Check if a shop object with id X exists? If yes? Update object by pushing a new item to the array.

**Code**

I'm using C# with the Mongo Driver Nuget package. And I've come up with the following code:

```
public async Task<MongoCmdResult> CreateOrUpdate(ShopDocument shopDocument)
{
    var filterLibrary    = Builders<ShopDocument>.Filter;
    var filter           = filterLibrary.Eq(shop => shop._Id, shopDocument._Id)
            & filterLibrary.ElemMatch(shop => shop.Products, products => products.ProductId != shopDocument.Products[0].ProductId);
    var updateDefinition = Builders<ShopDocument>.Update.Push<ShopDocument.Products>(shop => shop.Products, shopDocument.Products[0]);
    var updateOptions    = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<ShopDocument> { IsUpsert = true };
    return await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, updateDefinition, updateOptions);
}
```

**Problem**

Although this code at first seemed to do the job perfectly, it started throwing some exceptions when called parallel multiple times: `Command findAndModify failed: Non-unique id.`.

My theory to why this (sometimes) fails when executed in parallel (in this example 2 parallel calls) is that during the collection read in both calls (applying the filter) there appears to be no document with the given id. MongoDB decides both queries should insert. The first one succeeds, the second one fails on `Non-unique id` cause the other query was faster and the to be inserted document already exists (based on id).

In this scenario, is there no other (read: better) way than to try catch the `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` method and retry once in case of a duplicate key error? Is there for example something that I could change in my update options or filter to account for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a better way currently other than catching that error and dealing with it accordingly in your code.

Your theory is correct, in that 2 threads happen to insert at exactly the same time. However this is kind of expected in a concurrent system.

I find that the best way to deal with this is:

1. try to insert
2. if failed, do update instead

Which is basically the condition you have described in your question.

In the upcoming MongoDB 4.2, this can be resolved automatically by using the [update method with the upsert option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). This is described in detail in [SERVER-14322](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14322), where the server will automatically retry performing the upsert in cases where it is detectably safe to do so.